# Exclude custom taxonomy

Tags: web, wordpress

I have a custom post type 'listings' and one of its taxonomies is 'status'. I want to create two widgets:

1. display all 'listings' WITH 'status' 'sold'.
2. display all 'listings' WITHOUT 'status' 'sold'.

I've achieved the first widget using

```
query_posts( array(
    'status' => 'sold' )
);
```

I can't create the second widget. It should be like "status => !sold", or exclude sold. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly...

```
query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'status',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'sold',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

This code excludes `status => sold` from `post_type => listings`

Comment: NO **NEVER EVER** use `query_posts`. It is resource intensive, is slow, breaks pagination and breaks the main query. Rather use `WP_Query`

Comment: I use `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` for the main query. I can also use `posts_per_page` if I wanted pagination. Although I'm not quite sure about the "resource intensive and slow" thingy... some forum said the performance is the same and that the only difference is that it replaces the main query.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code when you need status = sold

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'status',
            'value' => 'sold',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$myQuery = new WP_Query($args);
```

And below code when you want status != sold

```
$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'status',
            'value' => 'sold',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$myQuery1 = new WP_Query($args1);
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer for the proper use of `WP_Query`